# How to use Comparable correctly for Strings in Java?

Tags: java, object, comparable

I have following interface:

```
public interface Generator <T> {
public T next ();}
```

and the class that has several methods and fields. I will write my code in order so you will understand my probem.
Class:

```
public class Example implements Comparable <Example>{}
```

This class has fields like:

```
private String name;
private static int count;
private int ID = count ++;
private static char [] chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".toCharArray();
```

Constructor:

```
public Example (String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Method that returns information about class:

```
public String toString (){
    return "ID #" + ID + ", name: " + name;
}
```

Method that produces new classes:

```
public static Generator <Example> generator (){
    return new Generator <Example> (){
        public Example next() {
            Random rand = new Random ();
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder ();
            for (int i=0; i!=10; i++)
                str.append(chars[rand.nextInt(chars.length)]);
            return new Example (str.toString());
        }
    };
}
```

and this incomprehensible method that I can not understand:

```
    public int compareTo(Example o) {
    return (this.name < o.name ? -1 : (this.name == o.name ? 0 : 1)); // It does not works... :(
}
```

Generic method that produces array:

```
    public static <T> List <T> array (List <T> list, Generator <T> gen, int size){
    for (int i=0; i!=size; i++){
        list.add(gen.next());
    } return list;
}
```

and main method when I am trying to compare sort array:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    List <Example> list = new ArrayList <Example> (); // Created the array;
    array (list, generator(), 10); // Filled the array;
    Collections.sort(list); // Doesn't work :(

}
```

I'm sorry for my English. English is not my native language.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return (this.name < o.name ? -1 : (this.name == o.name ? 0 : 1)); // It does not works... :(
```

in your `compareTo()` implementation you are comparing String with `<` operator which is invalid. you can do it like

```
return this.name.compareTo(o.name); // for natural string comparison
```